# Concatinating randomly selected value from df2 with df1

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

So I have a `Student` dataframe like this,

```
ID,STUDENT_ID
1,0123
2,9876
3,4567
4,2986
```

and a `Courses` dataframe like this,

```
ID,COURSE_ID
990,CourseA
991,CourseB
992,CourseC
```

What I'd like to do is to ***RANDOMLY SELECT ANY 2 COURSE_IDs from the Courses dataframe and append it to each indiviual STUDENT_ID in the following format***.

```
ID,STUDENT_ID,COURSE_ID
1,0123,CourseA
2,0123,CourseB
3,9876,CourseB
4,9876,CourseC
5,4567,CourseA
6,4567,CourseC
7,2986,CourseA
8,2986,CourseC
```

Basically, I have to create 1 replica of each individual `STUDENT_ID`. Then after selecting the 2 random `COURSE_IDs`, attach it to the `STUDENT_ID` one by one. I only have to make sure that the randomly selected `COURSE_IDs` for each `STUDENT_ID` is always unique i.e., a *STUDENT should **not** receive the same course twice.*

I know I can use

```
df1 = df1.append([df1]*1, ignore_index=True)
df1['ID'] = np.arange(1, len(df1) + 1)
df1.sort_values(['STUDENT_ID'], inplace=True)
```

to make a duplicate of my `STUDENT_IDs`.

I also know that I can use

`df2.sample(2)`

to randomly select 2 `COURSE_IDs.`

But I'm not sure how to combine these 2 to get the expected result. I'd really appreciate some help here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) in a list comprehension to create your `array` of random courses, then [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to create the desired output:

```
import numpy as np

rand_courses = np.hstack([Courses['COURSE_ID'].sample(2).values for i in range(len(Student))])

Student.loc[Student.index.repeat(2)].assign(COURSE_ID=rand_courses, ID=np.arange(len(Student)*2) + 1)
```

[out]

```
   ID  STUDENT_ID COURSE_ID
0   1         123   CourseA
0   2         123   CourseC
1   3        9876   CourseB
1   4        9876   CourseA
2   5        4567   CourseA
2   6        4567   CourseB
3   7        2986   CourseB
3   8        2986   CourseA
```